# Get Transfer-Encoding chunked in Response Header by HttpClient

Tags: java, httpclient, chunked-encoding, response-headers, getmethod

I want to get the value of Location in Response Header by this code

```
HttpGet getRequest = null;
CloseableHttpResponse response = null;
getRequest = new HttpGet("https://wl-prod.sabresonicweb.com/SSW2010/B3QE/webqtrip.html?searchType=NORMAL&journeySpan=RT&origin=SGN&destination=DAD&departureDate=2016-01-31&returnDate=2016-02-01&numAdults=2&numChildren=0&numInfants=0&alternativeLandingPage=true&promoCode=&lang=vi_VN");
getRequest.setHeader("Host", "wl-prod.sabresonicweb.com");
getRequest.setHeader("User-Agent", defaultUserAgent);
getRequest.setHeader("Accept", "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8");
getRequest.setHeader("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.5");
getRequest.setHeader("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate");
getRequest.setHeader("Referer", "http://vietnamairlines.com/");
getRequest.setHeader("Connection", "keep-alive");

response = httpClient.execute(getRequest, context);
Header[] headers = response.getAllHeaders();
for (Header header : headers) {
    System.out.println("Key : " + header.getName() 
          + " ,Value : " + header.getValue());
}
```

However, the result I received that:

Key : Cache-Control ,Value : no-cache
Key : Expires ,Value : Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT
Key : X-FRAME-OPTIONS ,Value : SAMEORIGIN
Key : Pragma ,Value : no-cache
Key : Cache-Control ,Value : no-store
Key : Content-Type ,Value : text/html;charset=UTF-8
**Key : Transfer-Encoding ,Value : chunked**
Key : Vary ,Value : Accept-Encoding
Key : Date ,Value : Sat, 05 Dec 2015 08:36:16 GMT
Key : Server ,Value :

When I use Fiddler, I can get the value of Location Response Header like this:

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Cache-Control: no-cache
Expires: Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT
X-FRAME-OPTIONS: SAMEORIGIN
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-store
Location: https://wl-prod.sabresonicweb.com/SSW2010/B3QE/webqtrip.html?execution=e2s1
Content-Length: 0
Date: Sat, 05 Dec 2015 08:00:30 GMT
Server:
```

How can I get the value of Location in Response Header by HttpClient Get method ?

Comment: which client is in use and how do you config "HEADER" logs for that client?  that is all that fiddler is doing is listing the response.headers just like Curl -v would do.  https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/logging.html